# Codeigniter email validator always returns null to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some code that no matter what the email submits a NULL value. I have played with every validation rule I can and it still submits a NULL value for email when submitted.

## View

```
<?php php echo form_label('First Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dfirstName'); ?><br>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dfirstName', 'First Name' => 'dfirstName')); ?><br>

<?php echo form_label('Last Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dlastName'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dlastName', 'Last Name' => 'dlastName')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('E-mail :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'e-mail' => 'demail')); ?><br />
```

## Controller

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

//Validating firstName Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dfirstName', 'FirstName', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[15]i');

//Validating lastName Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dlastName', 'LastName', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[15]');

//Validating Email Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'e-mail', 'trim|alpha_numeric|max_length[30]');


if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('schedule_submit');
} else {
    //Setting values for tabel columns
    $data = array(
        'e-mail' => $this->input->post('demail'),
        'LastName' => $this->input->post('dlastName'),
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('dfirstName')
    );
    //Transfering data to Model
    $this->acom_insert->form_insert($data);
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    //Loading View
    $this->load->view('acom_success', $data);
}
```

Comment: In your form input array() your missing the `name` like `array('id' => 'firstname', 'name' => 'Something')` or try like here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_input

Comment: I have submitted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your view's form input parameters are wrong, for all 3 fields you are not using name parameters. You can follow this code -

```
<?php php echo form_label('First Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dfirstName'); ?><br>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dfirstName', 'name' => 'dfirstName')); ?><br>

<?php echo form_label('Last Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dlastName'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dlastName', 'name' => 'dlastName')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('E-mail :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what is wrong here, the only thing you missed is the NAME.

When posting values, the PHP relies on the name of the input type. So just put the name on each input element.

**This is your code**

```
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'e-mail' => 'demail')); ?><br />
```

**Here is what's missing**

```
<?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'demail','id' => 'demail', 'e-mail' => 'demail')); ?><br />
```

PHP posts are name not id :)

**EDIT**

I have edited my answer. Please try that, If that doesn't work, can you show the whole form with the form tag?

Comment: the first name and last name are submitting correctly, but the email is not.

Comment: edit worked like a charm. just has me curious why first name and last name were able to post to the db without the name fields. thank you for the help!!

Comment: Okay thanks, Can you give me an upvote and a check mark? I'll take a look at it. Weird though. I'll give an explanation again in a while!! @Humbrol2 :)

Comment: I read through and many would say there is no way to post without a name. I don't have my codeigniter right now but I think the cause of this is (Probably) The required formvalidation. The email is the only one that doesn't have a required in the form validaiton from my view :)

Comment: Whyd you need to just remove my check mark? Maybe just give me an upvote, I lost 15 reputation and a check mark wouldn't hurt.